# Odoo8 - how can I sort status bar and set default as new?

Tags: default, statusbar, odoo, odoo-8

I have created a new module in Odoo for helpdesk and I have 2 problems that I can't seem to fix or find information on so need some help.

I created a status bar (code):

```
state = fields.Selection({('new','New'), ('open','In Progress'), ('closed','Closed')}, "Status")
_defaults = {
    'state': 'new'
}



<header>
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="new,open,closed" clickable="True"/>
```

Even thought I have stated "new, open, closed"  it is showing in Odoo as open,new, closed.

I set the state default as new, even though I am not getting any errors, when I click on create it shows state as blank.

Any ideas on how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declared your field you gave it *a set* of options instead of *a list* of options. Sets in Python doesn't keep the information about items order, but lists do. For your declared order to be respected you just need to replace the set literal by a list literal:

```
state = fields.Selection(
    [('new','New'), ('open','In Progress'), ('closed','Closed')],
    "Status",
)
```

You can remove `statusbar_visible` from your view.

---

As for your second problem (with the default value) Emipro Technologies is correct. You need to declare the default value as an argument on your field:

```
state = fields.Selection(
    [('new','New'), ('open','In Progress'), ('closed','Closed')],
    default='new',
    string="Status",
)
```

Comment: Thank you.. so easy when you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields declaration seems that it's Odoo-8 code, in V8 _defaults is not there you need to write as below,

```
state = fields.Selection({('new','New'), ('open','In Progress'), ('closed','Closed')},"Status", default='new')
```

And there is no more logic to set sequence in status bar but then also try this,

```
<form string="String" version="7.0">
    <header>
        <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="new,open,closed" clickable="True"/>
    </header>
</form>
```